# Xcode 6.3 update cause working app to fail - what was working now doesn't

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I don't know if anyone else has experienced this, but I have an app I'm building and it was working just fine. Then I stupidly allowed mac to install and `xcode` update.  Next thing I know, I open the project and the build fails with 21 errors.  I have fixed 20 of them. Incidentally, anyone else finding this issue with `PF_Nullability` errors, [check this out](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/im-bNTazInU).

That worked for 20 errors, but the last one is in a function that was working correctly.  In this function, I query a data class on parse.com and get a random object to populate variables in my view `controller/app/whatevers`.  I am putting the function below so you can see the whole thing, but this is the erroneous line:

```
 countQuery.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (count: Int32, error: NSError!) -> Void in
There error: cannot invoke 'countobjectsinbackgroundwithblock' with an argument list of type '((Int32, NSError!) - Void in)'
```

Here is the whole function and here's to hoping it's just a syntax thing like the other 20 fixes:

```
     func CallData() {
    var countQuery = PFQuery(className: "QandA")
    countQuery.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (count: Int32, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
            var query = PFQuery(className: "QandA")
            query.skip = randomNumber
            query.limit = 1
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {
                    var object: AnyObject = objects[0]
                    self.Question = object  ["Question"] as String!
                    self.Answers = object  ["Answers"] as Array!
                    self.Answer = object  ["Answer"] as String!

                    if (self.Answers.count > 0) {
                        self.QuestionLabel.text = self.Question
                        self.Button1.setTitle(self.Answers[0], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                        self.Button2.setTitle(self.Answers[1], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                        self.Button3.setTitle(self.Answers[2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                        self.Button4.setTitle(self.Answers[3], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                    }
                } else {
                    NSLog("Something is wrong with the find request, dude.  Sorry. %@", error)
                }
            }
        } else {
            NSLog("Something is wrong with the count request, dude.  Sorry. %@", error)
        }   
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to get rid of that error?  Why it's not working now when it did work before?  Thank you.

Comment: Is PFQuery a 3rd party library? If so, you may have to wait for a compatibility update from them. Using Swift comes with some risk since it's an evolving beta language and you can typically mitigate this by not depending on 3rd party code. You can possibly try to rewrite the countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock line of code and see if swift 1.2 has updated the argument list, this could fix your error.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, I guess PFQuery is a Parse.com thing ... honestly not sure. Will check swift 1.2 to see if I can find anything, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one error eventually led to another, but I finally got it worked out ... it was basically syntax (casting errors also, I guess, but essentially syntax errors in the casting ... I guess ... a question mark here, an exclamation point there ... I'm a newb, so I really have no idea, just getting by with trial and error) but here is what worked:

```
  func CallData() {
        var countQuery = PFQuery(className: "QandA")
        countQuery.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (count: Int32, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) { let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
                var query = PFQuery(className: "QandA")
                query.skip = randomNumber; query.limit = 1
                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {

                        var object: AnyObject = objects![0]
                        self.Question = object ["Question"] as! String!
                        self.Answers = object ["Answers"] as! Array!
                        self.Answer = object ["Answer"] as! String!
                        if (self.Answers.count > 0) {
                            self.QuestionLabel.text = self.Question
                            self.Button1.setTitle(self.Answers[0], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                            self.Button2.setTitle(self.Answers[1], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                            self.Button3.setTitle(self.Answers[2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                            self.Button4.setTitle(self.Answers[3], forState: UIControlState.Normal) }
                    } else { 

                        NSLog("Something is wrong with the find request, dude. Sorry. %@", error!) 
                    } 
                }
            } else { 
                NSLog("Something is wrong with the count request, dude. Sorry. %@", error!) 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: So you updated to Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2 without even bothering to read the release notes that tell you about the changes in Swift 1.2? That seems pretty silly.

Comment: There is a tool to help convert your Swift 1.1 to 1.2 - Go to Edit > Convert

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just:

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode (needs developer account) and download Xcode 6.2 DMG
2. Rename in /Applications current Xcode 6.3 app (it's called just Xcode) to Xcode-6.3
3. Mount downloaded DMG, then copy Xcode to Applications.
4. Xcode now is Xcode 6.2

I use this approach so Xcode is always the last one. That way I can build old projects just switching to the right Xcode (I put all icons on Dock).

Note: this is a **workaround** to your main problem. In the near future you should transition to Xcode 6.3 & Swift 1.2, but in the meantime you can build again

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the link -- thought of this, but like you say, only a short term work around, and ... there is also the matter of already fixing 20 other errors ... that would now have to be "fixed" again.  :-)  doh!

Answer (score 1):

Download the last version of Parse to fixed this problem.

https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads/

Comment: Did that at one point -- it fixed some issue, but not this one -- but the code in the answer above ttly works.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool in Xcode to help convert your Swift 1.1 to 1.2 - Go to Edit > Convert

Comment: Oh yeah, I tried that when I was buried in errors ... didn't fix this issue ... caused new errors ....  but no worries, this is answered above.  :-)

Comment: I just tried this and got over 100 more errors. I did a git commit before doing this but trying to revert back and still having these 100+ errors :(